# JS .checked not working in for ... in loop - in IE11

Tags: javascript, loops, internet-explorer-11

I have the following function which works great in chrome, but in IE 11 doesn't.

It is designed to:

- Take a questionGroup value determining which group of questions we want an average score for
- Get a collections of the inputs on the page
- Loop through them
- If they are 'checked' then get the class name which determines the group the question is in
- Count the number of questions in the group we're looking for
- Get the total score for all questions in the group
- Divide the total score by the number of questions to get the average score for the group

  ```
  function getGroupScore(questionGroup) {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      var countOfQs = 0;
      var totalGroupScore = 0;

      for (var element in inputs) {

          if (inputs[element].checked) {

              var theQuestionsGroup = inputs[element].className;

              if (theQuestionsGroup == questionGroup) {

                  var answer = parseInt(inputs[element].value)

                  totalGroupScore += answer;

                  countOfQs++;

              }
          }
      }

      var groupScore = totalGroupScore / countOfQs;

      return groupScore;
  }
  ```

In debugging, the loop seems to never get passed the following stage:

```
if (inputs[element].checked)
```

Even though there are input fields that are checked

example of the form I'm looping through:

```
<form action="">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto; border: none;" id="reschecklist">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" valign="top" width="400"><h3>Questions</h3></td>
                <td colspan="5" class="center"><h3>Score</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="left"><strong>(not at all)</strong></td>
                <td colspan="3" align="right" class="right"><strong>(I am fully implementing this)</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading" width="400"><strong>Minimise overhead costs</strong></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="question"><p>Do you consider and identify ways to maintain machinery better and cheaper?</p></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" class="grp1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="question"><p>Do you regularly review your overhead costs i.e. can you identify how much they cost you on a monthly, 6 monthly, annual basis?</p></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="4" class="grp1" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" class="grp1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading" width="400"><strong>Set goals and budgets</strong></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="question"><p>Do you have a clearly set out vision and objectives for the business?</p></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="4" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="5" class="grp2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="question"><p>Do you routinely (every 3-6 months), with your partner/s or your team, take a hands off view of the business and discuss objectives, performance etc?</p></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="1" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="2" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="3" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="4" class="grp2" /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="5" class="grp2" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for-in` is not how you loop through an HTMLCollection. Use a simple `for` or [one of the "array like" approaches in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) (which also explains why `for-in` isn't the right choice here). I suspect the problem is that there are no enumerable properties in the `HTMLCollection` on the platform where you're seeing the problem.

So for instance:

```
for (var element = 0 ; element < inputs.length; ++elements) {
```

In modern environments, `HTMLCollection` (what you get back from `getElementsByTagName`) may have the non-standard extension making it iterable (ES2015+) and giving it a `forEach`. If not, you can easily add it:

```
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" &&
    NodeList.prototype &&
    !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, direct assignment is fine here, no need for `Object.defineProperty`
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
if (typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" &&
    HTMLCollection.prototype &&
    !HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, direct assignment is fine here, no need for `Object.defineProperty`
    HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

That code does both `HTMLCollection` and `NodeList` (what you get from `querySelectorAll`). Then you can use:

```
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.checked) {
        // ...
    }
});
```